# Batch file output does not work as expected

Tags: batch-file, escaping

First, before it gets suggested, I have `DELAYEDEXPANSION` enabled globally via the registry, and I've tried enabling locally as well.

I'm trying to echo HTML preprocessing code into the batch file, and the following works as expected:

```
echo ^<!-- @include ./%b%/main.inc --^> >> search-%b%.inc
```

For example, it echos `<!-- @include ./criteria/main.inc -->` into file search-criteria.inc

However, the following does not:

```
echo ^<!-- @include ./!b!/main.inc --^> >> search-!b!.inc
```

While, I'd expect the result to be the same, what shows up in search-criteria.inc is `<b/main.inc -->`

What's happening here?

*As a side note* - Sublime seems to know there is an error in my syntax, because highlighting breaks after the first `<`.  If I escape the first `!`, the highlighting starts working again, but the result is the same.

Comment: If delayed expansion is enabled, then your first code must be failing as well - delayed expansion will remove the lone `!` from the output. The fix would be the same - double escape it as `^^!`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the first `!` with a double-caret `^^!`. Batch is interpreting `-- @include ./` as a variable.

Comment: for inside a batchfile, you need to double-escape it_ `^^!`

Comment: @Stephan: Yes - quite so. Corrected.

Comment: Funny.  I get it.  Wouldn't have ever thought to use `--`, `@`, `.`, or `/` in a variable name.

Comment: @user1167442 you can even use some non-printing characters in variable names.

Comment: @jwdonahue - what an esoteric scripting language.